# Set mac mini as a peripheral device using core bluetooth framework

Tags: iphone, ios, core-bluetooth

I am working with the core bluetooth framework . I want set my mac mini which is BLE enable device as a bluetooth peripheral which advertise the data . I have tried to create mac application for the same :
My application implements **CBPeripheralDelegate** protocol and in view didDidLoad method i have implemented following code :

```
peripheralManager=[[CBPeripheral alloc]init];
peripheralManager.delegate=self;
```

But its not working . Is this sufficient ? Or really OSx application supports the peripheral mode ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OS X currently doesn't support peripheral mode -- only central.  iOS, however, can act as either a peripheral or a central.

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing CBPeripheral in your code not CBPeripheralManager.

Here's an example from a project I'm working on:

```
//Initializes peripheral manager
-(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheralManager
{
  if (_peripheralManager == nil)
  {
    _peripheralManager = [[CBPeripheralManager alloc]initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
  }
  return _peripheralManager;
}
```